# If NSTemporaryDirectory returns nil

Tags: iphone, temporary-files

According to the documentation, `NSTemporaryDirectory()` can return nil. I need to save some temporary files in the device. What should I do if `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returns nil? Should I create a folder elsewhere? If yes, where? Or should I just show a message to the user?

Comment: when would it return nil?

Answer (score 0):

A potential alternate path here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:

(in the event the hashtag fails to scroll you down the page, check out `-[NSFileManager URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:]`)

Comment: What is the advantage of using NSTemporaryDirectory then? In the documentation it even says I have to delete the files I create in the temp directory when I don't need then anymore.